# how to fix the error connect timed out on sendmail php in the windows server 2021

Tags: php

Sory my English in not good but i can try to explain my problème

i have a problem in my php code. I use sendmail and gmail smtp server for send a mail to users of my application for validated the inscriptions. When i am in my PC with xampp a mail go very good it's okay but when i upload my project in my server (i use windows server 2012 and i have install xampp in my server. i use remote desktop of windows for connect me in my server) all the fonctionalities of my application give but the send mail doest not give and when i go to see the file error.log of the directory sendmail of my server xampp i have a message "connect timed out" please what is the problem i have remove the fireall of my server, i have open the port 587 on my server but anything i do don't give  please help me i am not so good in network

Comment: Why don't you use PHPMailer, or some similar library, and send the emails directly to Google's SMTP (or better, using their Oauth2-solution) from PHP? Less complexity, which means less points of failure and more portable code.

Comment: `i have remove the fireall of my server,`...bad idea, and totally unnecessary. `i have open the port 587 `...inbound or outbound? See if you can telnet to gmail's server on 587 from your command line, that'll tell you if the port is definitely open outbound or not.

Comment: a bothe inbound and outbound i have open a both because i dont know which is necessaire but it still didn't work

Comment: how can do for telnet a server gmail in command line please i'm not very good in netwok i have try to do a command "netstat -an" after the opening of the port but i have not saw the port 587